# Pandas: multiply column by column from another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes, both indexed by a date column called `month`. The first, `df1`, has eight rows. The column I care about is `df['num_percent']` and it looks like this:

```
2015-02-01    0.071549
2015-03-01    0.070368
2015-04-01    0.069291
2015-05-01    0.068394
2015-06-01    0.067452
2015-07-01    0.066302
2015-08-01    0.065543
2015-09-01    0.064591
Name: num_percent, dtype: float64
```

The second dataframe has 100,000 rows. The column I care about is `df2['total_quantity']` and a sample of it looks like this:

```
2014-11-01    324199
2014-12-01    378443
2015-01-01    367379
2015-02-01    336863
2015-03-01    380268
2015-04-01    386292
2015-05-01    373213
2015-06-01    403343
2015-07-01    414310
2015-08-01    403684
2015-09-01    420922
Name: total_quantity, dtype: int64
```

I want to add a new column to `df2` which is the value of `df2['total_quantity']` multiplied by the corresponding value for the month in `df1`.

How can I do this?

If I try:

```
df2['percent'] = df2['total_quantity'] * df1['num_percent']
```

I get `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`.

**UPDATE**: Here's some data and code to replicate the problem:

```
data = {'month': ['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01'],
        'num_percent': [0.4, 0.5, 0.6]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df1['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['month'])
df1 = df1.set_index('month')

data = {'month': ['2014-01-01', '2014-02-01', '2014-03-01', '2014-01-01'],
        'org': ['00K', '00K', '00K', '00L'],
        'total_quantity': [1000, 1000, 2000, 1000]}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2['month'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['month'])
df2 = df2.set_index('month')

# Both of these produce ValueError: cannot reindex... 
df2['percent'] = df1['num_percent'] * df2['total_quantity']
df2.loc[df2.index.isin(df1.index), 'percent'] = df2['total_quantity'] * df1['num_percent']
```

Comment: Can you post code and data to reproduce your error, this should just work as it will produce `NaN` where the indices don't align

Comment: @EdChum sorry about that, have added some.

Comment: So what is the desired output here? you have duplicate values in your `df2.index` hence the error, when you have duplicate index values are your row values also duplicated?

Comment: I've posted a method, basically you can `join` the dfs and then multiply the columns

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you [`join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) the dfs first then you can then multiply:

```
In [24]:
df3 = df1.join(df2)
df3['percent'] = df3['num_percent'] * df3['total_quantity']
df3

Out[24]:
            num_percent  org  total_quantity  percent
month                                                
2014-01-01          0.4  00K            1000      400
2014-01-01          0.4  00L            1000      400
2014-02-01          0.5  00K            1000      500
2014-03-01          0.6  00K            2000     1200
```